# What is the appropriate way to delete a service in Service Fabric?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-service-fabric

I have an application running in service fabric.  One of the services that compose the application is a stateful service that only has a run method. It queries other services, does some record keeping as it goes, and then produces an output.  Upon successful completion of the work, it saves the output to Blob Storage and then deletes itself.  I use this for on demand elastic compute around reporting.

If I call into the ServiceManager service to delete the service itself, it appears to deadlock.  This makes sense to me, since the call is likely awaiting the run method's completion before returning to the caller (in this case the caller is in the run method itself so it is effectively awaiting itself).  My next approach was to essentially ignore a Task to asynchronously delete the service like so:

```
protected override async Task RunAsync(CancellationToken can)
{

    //do work as described above

    Task ignored = Task.Factory.Run(async ()=>{
       await s_FabricClient.ServiceManager.DeleteServiceAsync(/*blah blah*/);
    }
    await Task.Delay(30000);
}
```

What is the appropriate way to delete a service, when I know the service should under all circumstances be deleted. I would like to avoid a 'manager' service which tracks these things, because right now they are very well self contained.

Comment: Did you consider using an Actor for this? It could become alive by means of a Reminder, and be GC'ed automatically when it's done. Considering you can have thousands of instances, Actors would produce a lot less overhead, as they share a Service process.

Comment: By default so do reliable services. You have to explicitly say you want a service instance to run in its own process.  Actors are less ideal, especially with timers.  There is a lot of overhead to run timers especially since I would also have to run a reminder to 'wake up' an actor if the process died.

Answer (score 2):

So the only solution I have found is as follows:

Before, I was using the DeleteServiceAsync (Uri) override which was deprecated.  When I saw this warning (embarrassed to say i hadn't checked warnings in a while).  I converted to the DeleteServiceAsync(Delete​Service​Description) overload which has a property called ForceDelete.  This basically does not give the service a chance to gracefully shut down.  Since the service itself is making the request, and I know that by this time my service is done working, I can safely call this.

It may not be the end all solution for every use case, but this seems reasonable given my requirements.

```
s_FabricClient.DeleteServiceAsync(new Uri("fabric:/myapp/myservice/instance123"));
```

Is now:

```
Uri serviceUri = new Uri("fabric:/myapp/myservice/instance123");
DeleteServiceDescription description = new DeleteServiceDescription(serviceUri)
{
 ForceDelete = true
};
s_FabricClient.DeleteServiceAsync(description);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I do

```
private async Task DeleteSelf(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
       using (var client = new FabricClient())
       {
            await client.ServiceManager.DeleteServiceAsync(new DeleteServiceDescription(this.Context.ServiceName), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), cancellationToken);
       }
}
```

Then, in last line of my RunAsync method I call:

```
await DeleteSelf(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

The `ConfigureAwait(false)` will help with deadlock issue as it will essentially return to a new thread synchronization context - i.e. not try to return to "caller context".  The `ForceDelete` flag is now not required either.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the service by using powershell command 
Remove-ServiceFabricService 
Please have a look here for documentation 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/servicefabric/Remove-ServiceFabricService?view=azureservicefabricps

The deadlock issue could be due to your code does not check for cancellation token. The idea is when you stop tell service fabric to stop a service cancellation token should be passed into your code. If you code dont check for the token then service fabric can not gracefully stop the service. This is the bit

```
  //do work as described above
```

Comment: This is not addressing the concern.  These services come up and down on demand, it's a new service instance to run the report.  There could be thousands running at any given time and I don't want (nor can I) manually be creating or deleting these services.

Comment: Can you do powershell or a different service to automate the create/remove service using the service fabric command when your service has finished the work?